# Azure function logging doesn't appear to be working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm able to successfully call my functions and make them do what I want them to do. The problem is that it doesn't look like the logs are being saved anywhere and I don't see how I can view them. Which I'll want to do in the event of an error. As a test I have my working function just doing a log.Info as soon as it's called. When testing locally it prints the message to the console. I believe I've enabled everything correctly but let me explain what I've done in case I didn't.

In my app service, under Monitoring -> Diagnostic Logs, I have enabled everything. Application Logging (filesystem) verbose, Application Logging (Blob) verbose (with the storage location set), detailed error messages and failed request tracing turned on.

In my function, I'm using the TraceWriter object that's passed to my run method (I started from a template).

**Please note that functions are set to require authentication.** If I click on the "Monitor" tab nothing appears. It just says "Loading..." forever and there's no information. Perhaps this is because of the authentication?

I used the Azure Storage Explorer to browse to my blob. The "log" blob exists, and I do see a set of nested directories that lead up to now. However it just contains a 354 byte file that contains a few lines of some random info. This file never seems to update or get larger.

I used FTP to try and browse to where the logs might be, but there's no directory on there that contains any log files.

I also went to KUDU for my function app ({myfunctionapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions). While I do see that my function was called successfully, I don't see anything from the call to log.Info anywhere.

I tried using a different logger, and as a test did: System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("test error");

I also don't see this message appearing anywhere.

Am I missing something as far as set up goes? Is the problem the fact that I require authentication? If it's the latter, is there still a way to view logs? I definitely have to have auth enabled. Thanks. And if it helps, below are links to what my settings and the monitor tab look like.

Settings: https://postimg.org/image/u57m2xbl5/
Monitor: https://postimg.org/image/uou10arch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication should not cause any problems with logging and Log.Info should work out of the box, no setup required.

I highly recommend that you enable AlwaysOn for your dedicated function app. The long loading of the Monitor tab could be because your site is in a 'cold' state, where it takes longer to start up.

If you go to {myfunctionapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole and navigate to LogFiles/Application/Functions do you see any expected logs there? Also, when you run a function from the portal do you see logs in the log window?

Comment: So I am seeing stuff in the directory you mentioned. I'm also now seeing it in my table storage (not blob though but don't really care, so long as it's somewhere). I think I may have just been looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I did enable "always on" as you suggested just now but the monitor page never loads or changes. I'm assuming this is due to authentication being enabled? I've seen another SO topic on how enabling auth causes these "Error: We are unable to reach your function app (Unauthorized).." messages to appear in the portal, which I am also having and that it's a known issue.

Comment: Try opening browser developer tools to see if there are any errors logged in the console or if any network requests are returning failures when you access the monitor tab, might help shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I see this in the console when I go to the monitor page: "{"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"host.String":["A value is required but was not present in the request."]}}". And this: {myfunctionapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions/undefined/invocations?limit=20:1 GET https://{myfunctionapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions/undefined/invocations?limit=20 404 (Not Found)
zone.min.js?v=39bd38aa:1 GET https://{myfunctionapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions/undefined/invocations?limit=20 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ok, that 'undefined' is the root of the problem.

When you say you have 'authentication enabled', are you using App Service Authentication or function level authentication?

Looking at the functions portal code on github it appears that you'll get an undefined host id if you have App Service Authentication enabled and not set to anonymous (https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/blob/f51c32f5395c444ee1d8aad60fa26fdb5e209e72/AzureFunctions.Client/app/services/functions.service.ts#L708)

Comment: Both my app service AND my functions have authentication enabled (the latter set via Function App Settings -> Configure Authentication). I also have my functions set  to use "Anonymous" for "Authorization level".

Comment: I just wasted a few hours investigating this.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me if I had Fiddler open....close Fiddler and all is good.